# How do you write a toggle switch with Bootstrap 5 and simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, bootstrap-5

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#switches. A toggle switch is another way to format a boolean checkbox.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@location) do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :pre1890 %>
```

Results in a default checkbox.[image: Screenshot of default] I'd like a toggle switch or maybe a labeled button. [image: Toggle from Bootstrap website]

I think I've seen JavaScript solutions for pre Bootstrap 5, but if JavaScript is required I'll live with the default. Thank you.

Comment: If you already have installed simple_form with bootstrap initializer. adding `form.input :pre1890, as: :boolean` should work for you

Comment: Otherwise try `form.input :pre1890, wrapper: :vertical_boolean`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Thank you. Still getting default checkbox. I'll add a screenshot to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this config in `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`

```
  config.wrappers :bootstrap_toggle, tag: 'div', class: 'form-check form-switch', error_class: 'form-group-invalid', valid_class: 'form-group-valid' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'form-check-label'
    b.use :input, class: 'form-check-input', error_class: 'is-invalid', valid_class: 'is-valid'
    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback' }
    b.use :hint, wrap_with: { tag: 'small', class: 'form-text text-muted' }
  end
```

and configure this to boolean

```
config.wrapper_mappings = {
  boolean:       :bootstrap_toggle,
  # ....
}
```

NOTE: If you are using bootstrap with simpleform check this https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#bootstrap

Or refer this code

```
  config.wrappers :vertical_boolean, tag: 'fieldset', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'form-group-invalid', valid_class: 'form-group-valid' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly
    b.wrapper :form_check_wrapper, tag: 'div', class: 'form-check' do |bb|
      bb.use :input, class: 'form-check-input', error_class: 'is-invalid', valid_class: 'is-valid'
      bb.use :label, class: 'form-check-label'
      bb.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback' }
      bb.use :hint, wrap_with: { tag: 'small', class: 'form-text text-muted' }
    end
  end
```

at https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/123d3b3822cb8a23c6216261f32d5e1af139a087/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb#L66

Comment: Thank you. Didn't comprehend some of these moving parts. I didn't even see the below the first two code boxes and that did it. I had already reran `rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap`. Nice to know about this. For anyone seeing this later the line is now `<%= form.input :pre1890, wrapper: :bootstrap_toggle %>`. @deepak: I have `simple_form_bootstrap.rb` but `vertical_boolean` didn't work. I'll check on restarting server.